# Youtube analytics batch reports api not working

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I want to download the full assets report from corrosponding cms account of youtube in C#.For this purpose I'm using YouTube Analytics API's BatchReports.I have tries with following code:

```
var batchReportDefinitions = youTubeAnalyticsService.BatchReportDefinitions.List("content_owner_id").Execute();
var request = youTubeAnalyticsService.BatchReports.List(batchReportDefinitions.Items[0].Id, "content_owner_id");
var result = request.Execute();
```

But third line throws "backendError" exception.Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?
Any help will greatly apprecited. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The rule with YouTube API is that backend errors are not on your end, but on theirs, and you shouldn't get them.

Judging by your other posts, you're a content owner and have access to the ContentID api. This means you can email your TAM/Partner Manager, and ask for a trace token.

When they send you a trace token, you add that to your requests, and they will get a full log of the error you're getting, which allows them to assess bugs.

I would recommend doing this. Good luck!